# _ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I want to connect to a web server that has a self-signed certificate, with Requests:

```
try:
    requests.get(url, cert=PATH_CERTIFICATE)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    logger.info(e)
```

But it fails with the following:

> [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib

I got this certificate by running this command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -ssl3 -connect <hostname:port>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `verify` keyword, instead of `cert`:

```
requests.get(url, verify=PATH_CERTIFICATE)
```